# Invalid write size of 4

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind

Here is the code in question:

```
long number = atol(argv[1]);
long prime_limit = number / 2;
int * primes = malloc(sizeof(int) * prime_limit);
long i;
for (i = 2; i <= prime_limit; i++) {
    primes[i] = 1; # This is line 16
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
==9318== Invalid write of size 4
==9318==    at 0x40065B: main (003.c:16)
==9318==  Address 0x8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==9318== 
==9318== 
==9318== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==9318==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x8
==9318==    at 0x40065B: main (003.c:16)
==9318==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==9318==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==9318==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==9318==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==9318==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
```

I believe that the error has to be how I used malloc but I am not so sure.  The value of argv[1] is 600851475143.

Comment: I rolled back the edits. Correcting the original (faulty) fragment would make the (correct) answers look senseless, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your allocation fails:

```
=9318==  Address 0x8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

...which kind of makes sense since you're trying allocate, 600851475143 * 4 / 2, or 1201702950288 bytes, or 1.2TB.

`primes` is therefore `NULL` and you're trying to dereference it when doing `primes[i]`, causing undefined behavior.

For comparison, if you were writing past the bounds of a properly allocated chunk of memory, Valgrind would give output similar to:

```
==10088==  Address 0x51f104c is 0 bytes after a block of size 12 alloc'd
```

**Always check the return value of `malloc`**:

```
int * primes = malloc(sizeof(int) * prime_limit);
if (primes == NULL) {
    perror("Allocation failure!");
    /* handle error */
}
```

And don't try to allocate 1TB in one go...

Comment: Yeah, I guess I will need to figure this out with a different algorithm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are `0`-origin in C:

```
i <= prime_limit;
```

should be

```
i < prime_limit;
```

Otherwise `atol` is not safe and cannot do error detection. Use `strtol` to convert a string to a `long`.

Comment: The fact that it's 0 origin doesn't matter because I am not counting from 0, I am counting from 2.

Comment: @EduardoB The fact it is `0`-origin means the last element of the array is `primes[prime_limit - 1]` and not `primes[prime_limit]`.

Comment: @EduardoB Print the value of `prime_limit` to ensure it is not `0` or negative.

Comment: prime_limit prints out 300425737571.  Also, I tried to do a print inside the for loop to see if it was looping and it does not loop.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what ouah posted, I think you should check the pointer value returned by malloc(). It's possible that you weren't able to allocate the amount of memory you requested.

Comment: primes == NULL returns true.  So I guess there is a problem with malloc?

Comment: On the other answer, you said `prime_limit=300425737571`.  Since `sizeof(int)` is 4 bytes, the amount of memory you seem to be trying to allocate is a bit over 1TB.  So you probably didn't have enough memory.